# Making image grid like Tumblr templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for such dumb question, but how can I make an image or text grid like Tumblr using HTML and CSS?
Well, I mean something like this: [image]

Comment: Only with HTML and CSS? If javascript/jQuery is valid you have [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: That question is too broad. Post some code of what you have tried and ask about specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very broad question, but here is a basic example to get you going. You should utilise some floated columns, that each have boxes within them.

Demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYQjvQ

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block-l">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block-l">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-last">
    <div class="block-l">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block-l">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="cf"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background: #ccccff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block-l {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: #ccccff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.col-last {
  float: right!important;
}

.cf {
  clear: both;
}
```